# Apache ExectuorWatchDog hangs while writing to System.out/JtextArea

Tags: java, cmd, testng, synchronous, apache-commons-exec

I am executing testng.xml(having 40 Testcases) from cmd shell using Apache.commons.exec.Executor in java with following code :

```
public static void executeBatch(String folderLoc) throws Exception {
    try {

            String cmd_for_testng = "java -cp " + "D:\\project\\libs\\*;D:\\project\\bin" + " org.testng.TestNG testng.xml";
            CommandLine cl = CommandLine.parse("cmd.exe /k" + dir +" && cd \"" + "D:\\project" +  "\" && " + cmd_for_testng);
            DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler;
            ExecuteWatchdog watchdog;
            final Executor executor;
            resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
            watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(-1L);
            executor = new DefaultExecutor();
            executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(new LogOutputStream() {

            @Override
            protected void processLine(final String line, @SuppressWarnings("unused") int level) {
               Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") > -1) {
                            System.out.println(line+"\n");
                        } else if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf("warn") > -1) {
                            System.out.println(line+"\n");
                        } else {

                            System.out.println(line+"\n");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }));
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
        executor.execute(cl, resultHandler);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

However it hangs after executing 11-14 testcases , it stops writing into console and hangs forever. If I kill its process, the execution of testng.xml suddenly resumes however as now I have killed the executor process , I can't see console output.

Comment: What happens when you run your tests regularly without using watchdog ? Do they run to completion ? Also why do you want to start another JVM from the current JVM ? Can't you not use the TestNG APIs directly by creating a TestNG object and invoking its `run()` method directly ?